# Angularjs no content if cache is disabled

Tags: angularjs, caching

So I have place my ng-controller and call ng-init a function to load all my services for the content. But still there are no content loaded when my cache is disabled. I have place .then to all my API calls still not working.

EDIT:

I need to show the content here:

```
<ng-include ng-repeat="url in data.urls" src="fileName(url.id)"></ng-include>
```

then my function goes like this:

```
$scope.fileName = function(id){
   switch(id){
       case '1':
           return "mypage.html";
           break;
     ....and so on.....

  }
 };
```

Comment: Fine! post your code!

Comment: Show your code or it will be closed.

Comment: can ngCloak be the solution?